# How to write an expression that refers back on image on which it operates in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine. I'm trying to translate code that I have in R to Java Script, of which I have no knowledge. This is the particular bit of R code that I want to translate to JS:

```
...
SINDEC <- -SINDCM * cos(2*pi*(doy+10)/365)      # This seems to work

COSDEC <- sqrt(1-SINDEC*SINDEC)                 # <-- This is what I'm trying to translate
```

I can't figure out how to write the JS that is equivalent to that code in R.

This is code I've put together so far as a trial:

```
// Any image
var naip = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ").first();
// Get the date
var imgda = naip.date();
// ... and come up with day of year (DOY).
var doy = imgda.getRelative('day', 'year').add(1);

var pi = 3.141593
var rad = pi/180

// Latitude
var imla = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');

// More operations that lead to the line I need help with
var xsindecl = rad.multiply(23.45).sin();

var sndl1 = doy.add(10).divide(365).multiply(pi).multiply(2).cos()

var sindecl = xsindecl.multiply(-1).multiply(sndl1)

// This is where I need help. This is my attempt at the JS version of the R code above
var cosf = function(image) {
    return ee.Image().expression(
      'pow(0.5) * (1 - im * im)', {
      'im' : sindecl
  })
};

// Not tested
var cosdecl = sindecl.cosf(sindecl);
```

I get this error message:

```
Image (Error)
Parameter 'image2' is required.
```

Since I'm trying to make the image expression work on itself, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the mathematical operators used in Google Earth Engine: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_math. Here you can see that exponent is written as `**`. Thus, getting the `sqrt(x)` can be written as
`x**0.5`, so this should work:

```
var cosf = function(image) {
    return ee.Image().expression(
      '(1 - im * im)**0.5', {
      'im' : sindecl
  })
};
```

There is another mistake that you need to correct in your script. In this line, you need to cast `rad` as a number so GEE can apply the `multiply` method. Usually the errors that return a message similar to "x is not a function" are solved by casting the variable into an `ee.Object`.

```
var xsindecl = ee.Number(rad).multiply(23.45).sin();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the 2nd mistake. I didn't even catch that one. I have more questions in the pipeline as I try to figure this out. Obviously, one question at a time. :)